# Open OCaml module within class

Tags: ocaml

I have a Map module that I want to be in scope within a class. How do I open that module within the entire class?

This was my guess, but it was wrong:

```
module My_map = struct
    module Map = ...
end

class my_object =
    object
        open My_map.Map

        method ...
    end
```

But this isn't working. Is there a way to open the module at the class level and not within each method?

Specifically, the issue that I'm having is this:

```
module Data = My_map.Map.Make(String)
```

However, when I try to access functions (within the class) that I added to My_map.Map.Make, I get compiler errors saying they don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I looked through the OCaml grammar just now and I don't see a place to open a module for a class definition as a whole.

You can say something like

```
class c =
    let x = 4 in
    object method m = x end
```

So it might make sense to be able to say:

```
class c =
    let open My_map.Map in
    object method m = ... end
```

However the grammar doesn't allow it.

You can open the module globally, or maybe give it a short synonym that's less onerous to type in your class definition.

```
module M = My_map.Map
```

**Update**

Rereading your question, I can't shake the feeling that you think you *need* to open a module in order to use its symbols. This isn't true, opening a module is just for convenience. Any symbol that could be accessed by opening a module can also be accessed without opening the module, by using a full module path. In fact many (including myself) would tell you to avoid opening modules in all but a very few cases.

If you're just having trouble specifying the right module path, it would help a lot if you could give self-contained (smallish) code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: agreed, I would only open to reduce the length of the module path (core//batteries) or to use infix functions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can open your module in the  class definition.
However, you can "open" it in a function:

```
module My_map = struct
  module Map = (struct
    type t = int

    let f () : t = 3

  end)
end

class my_object =
  object
      method stuff = My_map.Map.(
        let x = f () in
        x + f ()
      ) 
  end
```

This way, you see you can use `f` twice without having to write `My_map.Map` twice.

---

Regarding the second part of the issue, as pointed out by Jeffrey Scofield, I'm not sure it is really related to opening a module.
Or perhaps would you have wanted (in my example), `f` to become a method of `my_object`?

I also don't think it's possible, and I don't see any reason it should.
Perhaps, what you want is inheritance?